# Django sorl.thumbnail

Tags: django, sorl-thumbnail

I have problem

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sorl'
```

I installed it and tried even again.

```
(env) PS path> pip install sorl-thumbnail
Requirement already satisfied: sorl-thumbnail in path\env\lib\site-packages (12.8.0)
```

Django starts with that env activated. Module was installed with env also activated. I tried also to pip install without virtual enviroment.

It's also added in Installed_Apps

```
    ...
    'simple_history',
    'widget_tweaks',
    'sorl.thumbnail',
]
```

Any tips?

Full Traceback:

```
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\threading.py", line 973, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\threading.py", line 910, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\d\Desktop\S\H\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper      
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\d\Desktop\S\H\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 110, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "c:\Users\d\Desktop\S\H\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 87, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "c:\Users\d\Desktop\S\H\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "c:\Users\d\Desktop\S\H\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper      
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\d\Desktop\S\H\env\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "c:\Users\d\Desktop\S\H\env\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 91, in populate        
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "c:\Users\d\Desktop\S\h\env\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 224, in create
    import_module(entry)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 972, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 984, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sorl'
```

Comment: I hide real path because of personal data, real "path" is correct and showing good location

Comment: are you using pythonanywhere as hosting ?

Comment: Have you installed the package in the same environment as you run your Django project?

Comment: The same enviroment, (now its installed on all of the pythons on system to try, no results),

I don't use any hosting for now

Comment: I have added full traceback.

Comment: Other packages works without problems.

Comment: have you run `python manage.py migrate` ?

Comment: `(env) PS path> python.exe .\manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: Blog, Shop, Warehouse, admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions, social_django
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
(env) PS path> python.exe .\manage.py makemigrations
No changes detected
`

Comment: have you try to see your python or django version if there are compatible with sorl-thumbnail ?

Comment: all looks good, the version is good